# Need help using a command button to copy selected cells from 1 sheet to another in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a 'live' budget document for my work - one where I can input some details (event, cost, authoriser, etc) on a 'front-end' and then use a command button to copy that information to a data sheet, where it is compared with defaults I have set and then fed back to the front end as an updated figure.

I need it this way to ensure security over the figures and the data from the majority of my team

Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klK4J.jpg)

I have tried various iterations of code from this site - but can't find anything that works at all

Really appreciate any help - have read support documents, etc, and can't find the right stuff!

Comment: Can you create the button?

Comment: hey @Cooper - created the button itself (physically) but have been unable to get a working script for it. Will try your suggestion below!

Comment: Yes. I just gave you a menu selection.  But if you want to use a button that you create,  just right click the button artwork and in the upper right corner three dots appear.  Click on them and one of the choices has something to do with a script and I think you have to give the script name.  When in this case is copyStuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Copying Stuff**

If you want a button on your sidebar you can use this menu and select Create Sidebar and a sidebar will magically appear with a copyStuff button on it.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Command Menu')
  .addItem('Copy Stuff', 'copyStuff')
  .addItem('Create Sidebar', 'createSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function copyStuff() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Source Sheet Name');
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Destination Sheet Name');
  var srg=ssh.getRange('D6:D13');
  srg.copyTo(dsh.getRange('A1'));//I guessed you might want to copy it here but I dont know.

}

function createSidebar() {
  var html='<input type="button" value="Copy Stuff" onClick="jsCopyStuff();" />';
  html+='<script>function jsCopyStuff(){google.script.run.copyStuff();}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

Comment: So this is pretty helpful!

One question i have now - it copies the data in a literal sense (cell color, etc) and it copies it down the column, not across the row

Any chance to take the data (from D6:D13) and display it across the row?

Comment: Currently it copies whatever you have selected but yeh I'm okay D6:D13.  What is the destination range?

Comment: So I guess I will give you my ideal scenario - I would love the script to take the data from selected cells within a range - ie: D6, D7, D9, D10, D12, D13 for example and then transfer them to the next available row on the data sheet - starting at A1:A6, then B1:B6,etc

Also - at the moment it literally copies the cell (including dropdown data), can we just copy the contents at the time?

Comment: What's the name of the data sheet?

Comment: Currently it's 'Data 1' - but I also have another ideal scenario, wherein it would check the value of a cell like D6, then if it's a certain value it allocates to 'Data 1', if another option, it goes to 'Data 2'